# How to configure Jekyll Syntax Highlight?

Tags: jekyll, pygments, kramdown, rouge

By configure I mean font size, font family, syntax highlight style, line numbers and so on. I have followed some tutorials but they don't worked for me.

What I did:

- added `markdown: kramdown` and `highlighter: rouge` to _config.yml;
- added a css theme from pygments directly in head / imported it in the `main.scss` file.

I tried this and the syntax highlight worked but in a limited way, cause I can't add the line numbers with `lineos`. I noticed that the `{% highlight lang_name %}` tag doesn't works, just the triple tildes.

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Pygments has been deprecated. For `highlight` tag, you may consider use `rouge` or maybe markdown code blocks with `highlight.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends to some extent on the theme that you are using. If you want to change only a few small things, the best way is to use the Inspect Element feature that comes with your browser.

1. Start up your website using `bundle exec Jekyll serve` and navigate to a page with syntax highlighted code.
2. Right click on a code block and select "Inspect Element". Something should open up on the side or below. It will look like this:

[image: Chrome inspect element]

3. Now play around with the color/font size as you see fit.
4. Then just copy the contents into the `main.css` file.

A tricky part may be finding the `main.css` or `main.scss` file for your theme. Try to grep for it the theme's directory (which you see using `bundle show theme-name`). For Minimal Mistakes, it is `\assets\css\main.scss` since this theme uses `scss`.